# Generate banded image quickly?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, image

I need to generate preview images of walls for display dynamically.  All of them will consist of bands of varied color and width and should look something like this:

[image: sample wall]

Right now I have it working but it's kind of slow (not terrible, but enough that it feels a little lag-y) and I'm wondering if there is a better way.

What I am currently doing is constructing wpf objects in code.  I construct a grid as the main container, then a stack panel that is the preview, then a textblock that has a label at the bottom (cropped out of this image, sorry), then I add border objects for each of the layers (bands) with a border thickness for the outline and the proper color as the background, etc.  Then i use

```
        RenderTargetBitmap bmp = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)gd.ActualWidth, (int)gd.ActualHeight, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
        bmp.Render(gd);
```

Where gd is the grid object that holds the stack panel and text block and then use this as the image source.

The reason I'm using image source instead of directly using the WPF objects is two fold.  First, I have other objects that are actual image files that need to load and preview, so they come is as image source, not a WPF visual.  Second I have a thumbnail and a full preview.  I would like to be able to show the thumbnail as a scaled down version of the preview and if it's wpf objects I don't think you can do that (at least not easily).

Anyway if anyone has an better way to do this I would definitely appreciate it...

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm misunderstanding but I don't think that solves my problem at all.  If this was a static number of layers even then I could use XAML and would be happy to do so, but it could be from one to theoretically infinite layers (realistically probably no more than 10).  How would you set up XAML code to handle that?  And if I do then what about where I have an image?  I have multiple objects (hundreds of thousands) and some previews are generated this way and some have actual image files that are loaded.  Also how do you dynamically scale to fit the thubmnail?

Comment: Just to be clear I would love to use pure XAML and get what I want with WPF graphics as you suggest, I'm just not sure how to go about it and your comment doesn't have the specifics to figure out how to do it that way...

Comment: `How would you set up XAML code to handle that?` - By using an `ItemsControl` and proper DataTemplates. Delete all your code and start reading [here](http://drwpf.com/blog/itemscontrol-a-to-z/) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521(v=vs.110).aspx). Basically all items-based UIs in WPF are done with an ItemsControl regardless of their visual appearance.

Comment: and regarding the scale, I already told you that WPF scales automatically, no need to worry about that.

Comment: I'm not sure why nobody has mentioned that you can create that 'image' with nothing more than a `LinearGradientBrush` and a `Rectangle`... there's absolutely no need for `BitMapImage`s or `Image`s at all.

Comment: @Sheridan the OP needs to also include bitmaps into the UI (from what I understand), hence my mentioning of itemscontrol, the rest of it are implementationdetails, but yeah you're right

Answer (score 2):

> if anyone has an better way to do this I would definitely appreciate it...

You can create your wall 'patterns' very easily using a simple `LinearGradientBrush` in a `Rectangle`. This is an approximation of your displayed pattern:

```
<Border BorderBrush="#FF393939" BorderThickness="10" Background="Black" Padding="2">
    <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Rectangle.Fill>
            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,0">
                <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="#FFAA6268" />
                <GradientStop Offset="0.195" Color="#FFAA6268" />
                <GradientStop Offset="0.196" Color="#FF8B8B8B" />
                <GradientStop Offset="0.204" Color="#FF8B8B8B" />
                <GradientStop Offset="0.205" Color="#FFE3E3E3" />
                <GradientStop Offset="0.395" Color="#FFE3E3E3" />
                <GradientStop Offset="0.396" Color="#FF6F6F6F" />
                <GradientStop Offset="0.404" Color="#FF6F6F6F" />
                <GradientStop Offset="0.405" Color="#FFFF" />
                <GradientStop Offset="0.595" Color="#FFFF" />
                <GradientStop Offset="0.596" Color="#FF555555" />
                <GradientStop Offset="0.604" Color="#FF555555" />
                <GradientStop Offset="0.605" Color="#FFD4B371" />
                <GradientStop Offset="0.665" Color="#FFD4B371" />
                <GradientStop Offset="0.666" Color="#FF555555" />
                <GradientStop Offset="0.674" Color="#FF555555" />
                <GradientStop Offset="0.675" Color="#FFC7C7C7" />
                <GradientStop Offset="0.97" Color="#FFC7C7C7" />
                <GradientStop Offset="0.98" Color="#FF5E5E5E" />
                <GradientStop Offset="1.0" Color="#FF5E5E5E" />
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Rectangle.Fill>
    </Rectangle>
</Border>
```

This XAML creates this output:

[image]

Please bear in mind that this could be generated very easily in a code method, where you would have far better control over the thickness of each line, whereas I just roughly estimated that. Also note that you need **two** `GradientStop`s for each colour/line... the start *and* the end offset.

---

UPDATE >>>

I can't really tell how you're using your images, but it might be worth noting here that you can paint the `Rectangle`s with images too:

```
<Border BorderBrush="#FF393939" BorderThickness="10" Background="Black" Padding="2">
    <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Rectangle.Fill>
            <VisualBrush Stretch="Uniform">
                <VisualBrush.Visual>
                    <Image Source="pack://application:,,,/WpfApplication2;component/Images/Image.png" />
                </VisualBrush.Visual>
            </VisualBrush>
        </Rectangle.Fill>
    </Rectangle>
</Border>
```

Comment: Interesting approach, I hadn't thought of that.  However it seems really difficult to do with a dynamic set of layers...  Creative way to keep in mind though...

Comment: Actually, I'd say that it was even easier to do programmatically than it is doing it in XAML. Each line has two offsets and the total width = `1.0`. A tiny bit of maths could work out exactly where each line should go.

Comment: True i suppose. However I already had the math in place to do stacked borders so for me it was easier to use that :).  This still doesn't address using image files loaded in so I can't mark it as the answer but I upvoted because it's very helpful and creative solution to keep in mind...

Answer (score 0):

Ok so what I ended up doing is informed by several of these and seems to be working pretty well.

After thinking about data templates like @HighCore suggested, I realized I could use a ContentTemplateSelector class to determine separate templates based on if it should be a bitmap or an automatically generated item like this.  Then I created standard XAML templates for each preview type type needed and fed them to the template selector.

Since I already had the code to generate the WPF visual elements for the layered preview I did some profiling and found out (not surprisingly) that generating the bitmap was the vast majority of the time needed.  I then just created a property on my view model that returned the WPF element I generated and made the template bind to that properly for the content source of the preview.

One other important thing that may be helpful to someone is my discovery of the ViewBox class which I had never used before.  This does exactly what I was talking about with scaling WPF elements to fit a box.  My thumbnail template is a viewbox with a specific size with Stretch="Uniform".  The content inside the viewbox is the wpf element or image.  In the full size version I also use a viewbox but set only a maximum size (so that if the content is over the max size it will scale down automatically).

Hope that helps someone...